# How to check that the delimited string has X number of elements? python

Tags: python, string, try-catch, delimiter

I need to check the number of elements present when i split a string by a delimiter.

```
>>> x = "12342foo \t62 bar sd\t\7534 black sheep"
>>> a,b,c = x.split('\t')
>>> a,b,c,d = x.split('\t')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 3 values to unpack
```

Other than `try-except` and `if-else` condition (see below), how else can i check that the delimited string has X number of elements?

```
>>> try:
>>>   a,b,c,d = x.split('\t')
>>> except:
>>>   raise KeyError('You need 4 elements after splitting the string')



>>> if len(x.split('\t')) == 4:
>>>   a,b,c,d = x.split('\t')
>>> else:
>>>   print "You need 4 elements after splitting the string"
```

Comment: whats wrong with try-except and if-else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can count the separator using [`str.count`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.count):

```
>>> "12342foo \t62 bar sd\t\7534 black sheep".count('\t') == 4 - 1
False
>>> "12342foo \t62 bar sd\t\7534 black\tsheep".count('\t') == 4 - 1
True
```

---

```
x = "12342foo \t62 bar sd\t\7534 black sheep"
if x.count('\t') == 4 - 1:
    a, b, c, d = x.split('\t')
```

BTW, I will use `try ... except ValueError`.

Comment: why do i need the -1?

Comment: @alvas, Because `n` separator will generator `n + 1` items.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to take the length of the list produced by `split`:

```py
>>> x = "12342foo \t62 bar sd\t\7534 black sheep"
>>> len(x.split('\t'))
4
```